# EF Core Value Converter In Oracle Wont Work

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

i use Ef core and Oracle

i have a Column in Oracle Database With Data Type NVARCHAR2(20)
but in my Class Model i want Convert It Decimal
this is Config For ValueConverter :

```
entity.Property(e => e.ColumnName)
                .HasMaxLength(20)
                .HasColumnType("NVARCHAR2(20)")
                .HasColumnName("COLUMN_NAME")
                .HasConversion(
                v => v.ToString(),
                v => v=="" ? 0 : decimal.Parse(v, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

and this my My Model :

```
public decimal? ColumnName{ get; set; }
```

but after use this query this error show :

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got NCHAR'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Convert Column Via Oracle Query with check for number combability

```
(case when REGEXP_LIKE(ColumnName, '^[[:digit:]]+$') then to_number(ColumnName) else 0 end) as ColumnName
```